# Compute visible vertices of a polygon

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, polygons

Given a simple polygon $P$ and a point $p$ within the polygon, I want to compute the vertices of $P$ visible from point $p$. A point $q$ is visible from point $p$, if the line segment $\overline{qp}$ is completely in the polygon $P$.

One can use the accepted answer [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54302/on-log-n-algorithm-for-disjoint-segment-visibility-problem) to compute visible vertices in $P$ from a point $p$ in $\mathcal{O}(n\log{}n)$.

My question is, does an algorithm exist to do it in $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are more algorithms to do so in $\mathcal O(n)$. The first is dated back to ElGindy and Avis in 1981, Lee 1983 and Joe & Simpson in 1985. The visibility algorithms use stack (the first one three stacks, further only one) and process vertices in order they appear at boundary.

[The visibility algorithms](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/books/ArtGalleryTheorems/Art_Gallery_Chapter_8.pdf) described in book *Art Gallery Theorems and Algorithms* by Joseph O'Rourke. The book is out of print, available online.

Also author wrote a paper [the vertex-edge visibility graph of polygon](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772197000114) with Ileana Streinu in 1996, which with Chazelle's linear time triangulation and slight modification (simply by adding two edges from given point) would solve the problem in linear time.